# Sending ArrayCollections via P2P Flex

Tags: p2p, arraycollection, event-dispatching

I have a question regarding P2P with flex.
When passing data between two applications using P2P. I get the following error:

```
 warning: unable to bind to property 'piece' on class 'Object' (class is not an IEventDispatcher)
```

I've spent a few days using Google to try and find a solution, but a can't get rid of that error. I've tried using ObjectUtils, direct assignment, and creating a new ArrayCollection WITH the ObjectUtils inside the parenthesis and still can't solve the problem.

Purpose of code:
  -> Two users connect via P2P
  -> **1st** user can manipulate pictures (stored as objects in the array collection).
  -> **1st** user sends updated ArrayCollection (with changed pictures) to **2nd** user
  -> **2nd** user's ArrayCollection gets updated and now sees manipulated pics

As far as my knowledge of Flex goes (fairly new to it), I properly Binded what needed to be binded. Using pop-ups and trace, I was able to see that the data from the ArrayCollection gets copied in properly, but it just doesn't want to display.

Here are some snippets of my code:

```
[Bindable]
public var taken:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection ([
    new picLayout(1,'sky.png'),
    new picLayout(2,'bird.png')
    ])

public function receiveSomeData(pass:ArrayCollection):void
{   
    // Want to replace current version of variable "taken" with
    // the one passed in using P2P
    this.taken= new ArrayCollection(pass.source);
}

public function sendSomeData(free:ArrayCollection):void
{   
    sendStream.send("receiveSomeData",free);
}

<s:Button click="sendSomeData(taken)" label="Update" />
```

Thank You for your help and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was and how to fix it - with partial thanks to these pages:

[Unable to Bind warning: class is not an IEventDispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575955/unable-to-bind-warning-class-is-not-an-ieventdispatcher)

[Flex Warning: Unable to bind to property 'foo' on class 'Object' (class is not an IEventDispatcher)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928081/flex-warning-unable-to-bind-to-property-foo-on-class-object-class-is-not-a)

I knew that the information was being successfully sent to the other peer, but the problem was that the **objects INSIDE** the ArrayCollection weren't made bindable.

My solution to the problem was as follows:

- Create a **loop** that sends each **object** in the ArrayCollection along with an **index** that tells you what value in the ArrayCollection you are streaming.
- Now, since you are "streaming" the data, overwrite the current ArrayCollection, using the **setItemAt()** function with **first** field as "**new ObjectProxy(passedObject)**" and the **second** field as the **passedIndex** (Note): the **ObjectProxy()** function forces the passed object to be **bindable**.

Here is an updated snippet of my code:

```
[Bindable]
public var takenPics:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection ([
    new picLayout(1,'sky.png'),
    new picLayout(2,'bird.png')
    ])

private function sendSomeData(data:Object, index:int):void
{   
    sendStream.send("receiveSomeData",data,index);
}

private function receiveSomeData(passedPic:Object,ix:int):void
{   
    // ObjectProxy needed to force a bindable object
    takenPics.setItemAt(new ObjectProxy(passedPic),ix);
}

public function sendPictures():void
{
    // ix < 2 because size of ArrayCollection is 2
    for (var ix:int = 0; ix<2; ix++)
        sendSomeData(takenPics[ix],ix);
}
```