# Flex: Accessing SQLite entry using 'getItemAt()'

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite

I have an array populated with input from an `SQLite` database. When I use this array as the dataprovider for a s:list then it will display all the objects in the array that I specify.
I would like to access some of the objects in the array, and have been trying to use `getItemAt()`. At the moment I can return the first object in the array, but changing the index (to `getItemAt(1)` for example), it returns nothing.

Ultimately I am aiming to populate an FX:Model with data entered elsewhere in the application and inserted into the `SQLite` database. The model then acts as the dataprovider for a pie chart. I can pass the first entry of the database on to the model/pie chart, but can't access others.

Some relevant sections of code are as follows. Trouble shooting tips would be appreciated.

```
[Bindable]
    private var GHGsource:ArrayCollection;
```

And then:

```
            GHGsource = new ArrayCollection();
        }
        for each ( var o:Object in event.data )
        {
            GHGsource.addItem(o);
        }
        FullList.dataProvider = GHGsource;
    }
}
```

Model setup:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Model id="GHG" >
<data>
<row>
<input>Enteric methane</input>
<Value> {GHGsource.getItemAt(0).answer}  </Value>
```

List setup:

```
<s:List id="FullList">
  <s:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
      <s:IconItemRenderer labelFunction="returnQuestion" messageFunction="returnAnswer">
        <fx:Script>
          <![CDATA[                             
            private function returnQuestion(item:Object):String
            {
                return "Question: " + item.question;
            }
            private function returnAnswer(item:Object):String
            {
                var response:String = "";
                if ( !item.answer || item.answer == "" )
                {
                    response = "(no response)";
                } else {
                    response = item.answer;
                }
                return response;
            }
          ]]>
        </fx:Script>
      </s:IconItemRenderer>
    </fx:Component>
  </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

This application is based on the database structures set out in [Daniel Koestler's survey ape application](http://blogs.adobe.com/koestler/2010/11/open-source-flex-hero-app-surveyape.html).

Perhaps an insight into how the s:List component accesses objects in an array will help here?

Additional detail:

Running in debug mode it seems as though that the objects are not binding correctly to the arraycollection.
warning: unable to bind to property 'xxx' on class 'Object' (class is not an IEventDispatcher)

I have tried to follow guides on the following links, but have not been sucessfull.
[link1](http://sunilanair.wordpress.com/2009/07/21/warning-unable-to-bind-to-property-asset-on-class-object/)
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252862/sending-arraycollections-via-p2p-flex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it.

```
   GHGsource = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    for each ( var o:Object in event.data )
    {
        GHGsource.addItem(o);
    }
    FullList.dataProvider = GHGsource;
 }
}
```

Becomes:

```
[Bindable]
private var passingArray:Array;
```

And:

```
   GHGsource = new ArrayCollection();
   passingArray = new Array();

    }
    for each ( var o:Object in event.data )
    {
        GHGsource.addItem(o);
        passingArray[o] = new ObjectProxy(event.data[o]);
    }
    // not needed as the list is no longer needed - FullList.dataProvider = GHGsource;
}
}
```

Then this works:

```
<fx:Declarations>
<fx:Model id="GHG" >
<data>
<row>
<input>Enteric methane</input>
<Value> {GHGsource.getItemAt(3).answer}  </Value>
```